# How do I fix my UV map

Tags: mesh, texturing

I'm trying to add textures to a character that got by making him in the sims 4 and using ninja ripper pull the meshes and textures onto blender but the problem I'm having is when I go to unwrap the meshes they don't fit onto the textures properly for example the pants are not put together properly and the legs are spread so they I can't get it even on the texture and I tried adding seams but I guess I added them in the wrong place so that failed what should I do?

[image: The pants texture in question]

[image: The mesh in question]

[image: The mesh once I unwrap it]

Comment: Hello and welcome :). Please take screenshots using *PrintScreen* key on your keyboard. https://www.take-a-screenshot.org/

Comment: Hi there - you may have to manipulate the faces in the unwrapped UV Map to put them on the right parts of the image. There are several tutorials but a lot of the usual shortcuts are available to you in the UV Editor - 'L' to select all linked faces, vertex/edge/face select mode, G to grab/move etc.

Comment: Justin Leppan - So you mean manually move everything to its proper place?

Comment: Yup - other guys might suggest a better option but it's all I can think of. Remember you can use different unwrapping techniques on different parts of the model. For example if you selected the front faces of the pants and did a 'project from view' unwrap, I think it would match the image quite closely.

Comment: Ok I'll try that thank you